# Is there any way to retrieve items from dynamodb table by applying filter condition on primary key

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to fetch items from a dynamodb table with some condition on primary key and I don't have any other values with me.I just know that some of records in the table have a different pattern for primary key (like contains a hyphen in it) which others don't.How do I achieve this in a simple way..Do I need to Scan the complete table get the result and filter the desired records

Some thing like "Select * from Student where Id like '%-%', as we do in sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to do a scan and filter. If the table has a lot of items it could be a slow and expensive process.

Comment: Yeah I used recursive scan with filter expression on the primary key. Recursive is required because dynamodb limits to 1MB record size for each scan and this is indeed expensive but since this is one time job with lesser records so should be okay for me in this situation